# How to update variable then write it on specific line or skip the name and password to write

Tags: python, python-3.x

im almost new to the python and i gave myself a little challange where i write bank without class or specific module then i just got stuck at updating the cash and balance

```
aaa aaa 1 1
bkhg lkhg 1 1
terat rtrt 1 1
aa aa 1 1
```

first name then password then balance and cash with them

```
num = 0
nums = 0
file = open("accounts.txt","a")

print("Welcome To the Bank")

def withdraw():
    while True:
        global nums
        global file
        amounts = input("How much do you want to withdraw? $\n(exit) or (back) or (amount)\n")
        
        if amounts == "exit":
            quit()

        elif amounts == "back":
            break

        elif amounts.isdigit():
            amounts = int(amounts)
            nums = int(nums)
            if amounts <= nums:
                if amounts > 0:
                    nums = nums + amounts
                    nums = str(nums)
                    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines():
                        login_info = line.split()
                        if username in login_info and password in login_info:
                            login_info.pop(0)
                            login_info.pop(0)
                            login_info.pop(0)
                            nums = login_info
                            nums = (' '.join(nums))
                            file.write(nums)
                    amounts = str(amounts)
                    print(amounts + "$ Has been withdrawen into your account!")
                    backorexit = input("If you want to go back (back) or If you want to exit (exit)\n")
                    if backorexit == "back":
                        break
                    elif backorexit == "exit":
                        quit()
                else:
                    print("We cannot accept 0 or less than that!")
            else:
                print("You dont have enough cash in with you!")
        else:
              print("Enter a number to deposit!")

    return amounts
                

def deposit():
    while True:
        global num
        global file
        amount = input("How much amount you want to deposit? $\n(exit) or (back) or (amount)\n")

        if amount == "exit":
            quit()

        elif amount == "back":
            break
    
        elif amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if amount <= num:
                if amount > 0:
                    num = num - amount
                    amount = str(amount)
                    print(amount + "$ Has been deposited from your account!")
                    backorexit = input("If you want to go back (back) or If you want to exit (exit)\n")
                    if backorexit == "back":
                        break
                    elif backorexit == "exit":
                        quit()
                    else:
                        print("Looks like you typed wrong answer try again!")
                else:
                    print("We cannot accept 0 or less than that!")
            else:
                print("You don't have enough currency in your account!")
        else:
            print("Enter a number to deposit!")

    return amount

def findbalance():
    global num
    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split() 
        if username in login_info and password in login_info:
            login_info.pop(0)
            login_info.pop(0)
            login_info.pop(1)
            login_info = login_info
            num = login_info
            num = (' '.join(num))
            return num

def findcash():
    global nums
    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split() 
        if username in login_info and password in login_info:
            login_info.pop(0)
            login_info.pop(0)
            login_info.pop(0)
            login_info = login_info
            nums = login_info
            nums = (' '.join(nums))
            return nums


def login():
    for line in open("accounts.txt","r").readlines():
        login_info = line.split()       
        if username in login_info and password in login_info:
            print("Correct credentials!")
            return True
    else:
        print("Incorrect credentials.")
        quit()

def register():
    global file
    usernamee = input("Please input your desired name\n")
    passwordd = input("Please input your desired password\n")
    file.write(usernamee)
    file.write(" ")
    file.write(passwordd)
    file.write(" ")
    file.write("1")
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()

while True:
    logchoice = input("(Login) or (Register) or (Exit)\n").lower()

    if logchoice == "login":
        username = input("Please enter your username\n")
        password = input("Please enter your password\n")
        login()
        findbalance()
        findcash()
        break
    elif logchoice == "register":
        register()
        break
    elif logchoice == "exit":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Sorry It Seems Like You Have Typed The Wrong Answer :( Try Again!")    

print("you have " + str(num) + "$ in your account and " + str(nums) + "$ cash with you!")

while True:
    choice = input("Here is a choice for you\n(exit) (withdraw) (deposit)\n").lower()
    if choice == "deposit":
        num = int(num)
        deposit()
    elif choice == "withdraw":
        nums = int(nums)
        withdraw()
    elif choice == "exit":
        quit()
    else:
        print("Sorry it seems like you have typed wrong answer")
```

In the code i wrote findcash findbalance then login and register. and cant update cash and balance while doing deposit or withdraw.

Answer (score 0):

It's your little challange bro.

> Happy Programming!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).